# VBLOOKUP and MATCH to discern issues in a column

Tags: vba, excel

To make things as simple as possible, let's assume I have 3 sheets. Sheet 1 contains names and teams. Sheet 2 needs to contain only names that pertain to a specific team. However, the names are inputted manually. How can I check Sheet 2 to ensure that all the names on it belong to a specific team, and output ambiguities to Sheet 3? It's important to note that there is additional columns and rows on the sides of each ever-changing name list, and these variances not consistent in each of the sheets.

Sheet 1

```
Seger, Bob          Team A
Hendrix, Jimi       Team B
Osbourne, Ozzy      Team C
Shepherd, Kenny     Team B
Rose, Axl           Team A
Keenan, Maynard     Team C
```

Sheet 2 (should be Team B only)

```
Hendrix, Jimi
Shepherd, Kenny
Rose, Axl
Keenan, Maynard
```

Sheet 3 (inaccuracies)

```
Rose, Axl
Keenan, Maynard
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the top of an unused column in sheet3 and fill down for subsequent matches.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$99)/NOT(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A$2:A$99, Sheet2!A$2:A$99, Sheet1!B$2:B$99, "team b")), ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your input, but I am trying to accomplish this exclusively in VBA. I have to idiot-proof my spreadsheets, and VBA is the only way to allow users to enter information without destroying formulas.

Also, there could end up being any number of entries for the names, and these sheets won't have defined tables. It's become a huge headache.

Comment: *"VBA is the only way to allow users to enter information without destroying formulas."* That's not true! You can easily protect sheets and it's formula so other users cannot change them accidentally, but still can enter data.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ if I protect the sheet, then users cannot enter information into inserted tables. The problem is that my sheets, as they are, contain formulas throughout and those formulas won't automatically transfer to new rows outside of a table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dictionaries

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub VerifyNamesInSheet()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Const SHEET_TO_CHECK As String = "Sheet2"
    Const TEAM_TO_CHECK As String = "Team B"
    Dim teamNamesDict As Object, misplacedDict As Object, valuesToProcess()
    Set teamNamesDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set misplacedDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        valuesToProcess = .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(valuesToProcess, 1) To UBound(valuesToProcess, 1)
        If valuesToProcess(i, 2) = TEAM_TO_CHECK Then
            If Not teamNamesDict.Exists(valuesToProcess(i, 1)) Then teamNamesDict.Add valuesToProcess(i, 1), valuesToProcess(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SHEET_TO_CHECK)
        valuesToProcess = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

        For i = LBound(valuesToProcess, 1) To UBound(valuesToProcess, 1)
            If Not teamNamesDict.Exists(valuesToProcess(i, 1)) And Not misplacedDict.Exists(valuesToProcess(i, 1)) Then misplacedDict.Add valuesToProcess(i, 1), valuesToProcess(i, 1)
        Next i

    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        .Range("A1").Resize(misplacedDict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(misplacedDict.Keys)
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I will test this when I get home from work to see if it processes as required. I haven't a clue why this was so difficult for me, but I tried several times and got frustrated. I will update after I check.